# iOS: Get string from QR code and paste it into an input field of browser

Tags: html, ios, input, qr-code

Is it possible to scan a QR code and send the data to an HTML input field of the browser in iOS? It can be done in Android by using custom keyboards or probably intents but is there a way for iOS to get a similar result? Google searches weren't that helpful, they only delivered results for default scanner apps or generators. So maybe you guys know a way.

**Edit:** The link seen above does NOT solve the problem. I don't want to scan a QR code and use it *inside* that app, I want to scan it and *send* it to the web browser.

Comment: No, it's a different case. I don't want to integrate a scanner into an app but get the data from the QR code and send it to the browser.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you had tagged it as HTML.

Comment: Yes. The data should be pasted into a text field to initiate a search.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious to know how and why would you do that on Android?

Anyway, I don't know anything about that in iOS7.

Comment: How: Like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tecit.android.barcodekbd.demo&hl=en
Why: I want to check-in customers by scanning their QR-codes and putting the value in an input field of a web application.